# Umbraco - Get Property by type

Tags: umbraco

I'm new to Umbraco, so this may not even be feasible. I've created my own Datatype using Archetype and want to be able to get an instance of that type on the page by type, not alias.
I know that I can do the following:

```
model.Content.GetPropertyValue("myAlias")
```

But I want to know if it's feasible to get the property by the type. Something along the lines of:

```
model.Content.GetPropertiesByType("TypeName")
```

which would return a list of controls on the page of that type?

Is this feasible?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve content based on a specific document type?

Comment: It's possible, but not exactly straight forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, but not exactly straight forward.

Take a look at the available Umbraco Data Services - you'll need to retrieve the DataTypeDefinitions from the `DataTypeService` and retrieve the `ContentType` for the Model's IPublishedContent using the `ContentTypeService`.

Once you have these, you can match up the `PropertyTypes` on the `ContentType` with the retrieved `DataTypeDefionitions` based on the `PropertyType`'s `DataTypeDefinitionId`.

The `PropertyTypes` have an `Alias` property which will match up with the Property Aliases on the Content itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the content service if you get the id of the datatype you trying to find the multiples of from the url when you edit/create the datatype.

```
   @foreach (var p in ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.GetById(Model.Content.Id).PropertyTypes.Where(p => p.DataTypeDefinitionId == -89))
        {
            <p>@p.DataTypeDefinitionId</p>
        }
```